# Why does "Sore Ga Seiyuu" play other anime's OP/ED as its ending song?

Tags: sore-ga-seiyuu

I found that when I watched *Sore ga Seiyuu* anime, the ED songs seems from the other anime. For example, in ep. 1, they sang *Evangelion* OP, and in ep. 2, they sang *Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei* OP.

Here are some examples.

1. [Evangelion OP ( Ep. 1 )](https://youtu.be/z6G_16zh510?t=23m19s)
2. [Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei OP ( Ep. 2 )](https://youtu.be/HykGVek1rzU?t=23m18s)

What's the reason they are doing that?

Comment: The song is all about voice acting and vocal performances in anime; thus, it plays famous anime songs during its ED to pay homage to the anime those songs came from.